# call GAPPS script service from AppEngine as authenticated user

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have implemented a templating/document generation via Google Appsscript (at least a proof of concept). I can publish this GAPSS script as a web service and I can call give service from GAE.

This is what works already :

- a GAPPS script that takes a file Id (the template) and merge field/values as parameters
- the GAPPS script copies the template to a new file (=resulting file) and performs the merge (enhanced find/replace basically).
- publish the script webservice
- call it from appengine

The problem is that the GAE application has authenticated Google or Google Apps users and that the template can only be accessed by the user on behalf of whom GAE makes the call to the script. The resulting merged file must be written back to the drive of given user as well. So the script should run authenticated as the GAE authenticated user.

I know there is the scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts
```

That allows me to install scripts into a Google's drive ? Or ?

Main question is on what strategy to follow here :

- do I keep the script owned by some service account ?
- should I copy the script to each of the application users (problem: keep versions updated, prevent end users from modifying the script and so on)
- Can I authenticate the script so the script can execute as the same GAE user that makes the request ? Maybe using a "Key for browser apps" from the API console ?
- Maybe I should make the call client side (from the webapp ?) And do the reverse.. the GAS script calls GAE for instructions and the authentication problem is off my back ... But then I must stream the template to the GAS script ?
- or should I be looking at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth and is this applicable in this case ?
- one other option to consider is UrlFetch/OAuthConfig in AppsScript, but that leaves me without the convenience of DocsList and DocumentService

Too many options ... what is the best strategy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way today to call a Google Apps Script deployed Web App with OAuth credentials. You should log that request at the [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Google Apps Script web apps are authorized the first time the user accesses the web app. The simplest way to do this would be to have a link in your App Engine rendered HTML to the Apps Script web app. The user can click on that link and authorize (establish the right cookies in the browser) so that the Script can be run as the user at the keyboard.

Take a look at this [example](https://googledrive.com/host/0BwzWIlBMCiR9SlZkbkFqZ21YeFk/) (you can see the client side JS code via view source). The "Start Share Message" starts the Apps Script auth workflow.

Hope this helps in envisioning how you would layout your app.

Comment: you have any idea what the scope  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts" allows you to do then ?