# Authenticate user to ContentService

Tags: google-apps-script

I am deploying a ContentService which executes as "the user accessing the webapp". I am writing an Android client to consume this ContentService and it's not clear how I can authenticate the Google user to the ContentService.

There are well known paths for doing this with [other Google APIs using OAuth2](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android) - could this apply to a service I make with ContentService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked about the same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157406/call-gapps-script-service-from-appengine-as-authenticated-user) and the answer is NO.

You must expose the currently logged in user directly with the authorization requests from the script.

Comment: That's unfortunate - I'll follow you're issue request. Thanks!