# Google Appscript approvals for public document

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization, google-sheets, email-attachments

I have a google spreadsheet that is shared with all members on our domain.  I'd like to have a script which will send the spreadsheet as an email attachment whenever one of the users runs the script.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542907/google-app-script-cant-attach-spreadsheet-to-email) as a guide, I arrived at the following code:

```
function sendEmail() {

  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); 

  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
  //var email = Session.getUser().getEmail();
  var email = "xxxxx@example.com";
  var subject = "Order Form";
  var body = "Please find the attached Order Form for drop-ship delivery.";

  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");

  var requestData = {"method": "GET", "oAuthServiceName": "google", "oAuthUseToken": "always"};

  var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="
      + ssID + "&gid=0&portrait=true" +"&exportFormat=xls";

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();
  MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xls", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xls"}]}); 

}
```

This code works, but only if I run the code from the script editor first (which involves authorizing access to the google mail account), and then authorizing the script when using the script.

So, I passed along the document to the order department, and again, it only works when EACH USER authorizes the script from the script editor, and then authorizes the script when using it.

Is there a way to eliminate the "authorizing by way of the script editor"?  I'd really not like to have to go into each users account to authorize this script for them (as well as have to remember to do the same for any new user created)?

I appreciate any help offered!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately NOT. see also my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157406/call-gapps-script-service-from-appengine-as-authenticated-user) and the answer by one of the google developer advocates.

You can vote for the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2897) I opened to push for a solution.